Function 'sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol)' confusingly treats indexes of results, how does it really work?
const char *column_buf ="SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info(?);";

int rc;

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, column_buf, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if(rc == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, table, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        const unsigned char *fCol = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
        const unsigned char *lCol = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);                      
    }                
}

Here, I am trying to pass a string from sqlite3_column_text to a variable inside of while loop block but sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0) does return 0 and 1 which I assume are the columns indexes. Meanwhile sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1) returns column names but it combines column names string in one index Ex. index[1] = "first_column second_column" . How does this function really work?

please provide a mibimal reproducible example.

See https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info, for full details of SQLite PRAGMAs.

Running the while loop block prints 0 and 1 which I assume are the columns indexes

This question is similar to: return sqlite3_column_text() to literal string. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I can't see anywhere that anything gets printed. What are you actually doing to see the results?

To see the result i just printf const unsigned char *fCol @Charlieface
